# Calculate how much tax a corporation owes

Tags: taxes

You often see articles about corporations that use tax loopholes to pay less tax. I'm not very experienced in the subject, but these articles must get the information from somewhere right. Where do they get it from? I imagine what I need for a given company is to calculate:

- the profits for a given country for a given year
- the corporation tax for a given country in a given year
- how much tax they actually paid to that country in that year

Then I can take the profit and the corporation tax value for a given year and calculate how much they should have paid, vs how much they actually paid.

Is there an online resource? Is this data even public? If it's not public, how do articles get this information?

I actually imagine it's A LOT more complicated than this, but this is my layman understanding. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tax returns for corporations are confidential, so if you see it in articles it was probably leaked.

Sometimes if the company has available stocks, then they give income reports to the public. This shows a lot like how much they made or lost that year... And I guess some people could assume if they lost 100 billion last year they could deduct it next year from there income if they made 150 billion next year and only have to pay tax on 50 billion. Something like that.

I'm sure there are a lot of people who know how taxes work and can make those correlations. And also the information could be leaked by a lot of people since the big corporations that you are referencing have a lot of people seeing that information.

There might be another way, but those are some possibilities.